# ReportViewer chart - x axis adding start and end dates

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, charts

Problem: how to not display the start date 31/05 and end date 16/06

These values are not brought into the control via the dataset (hence there can never be any data) as shown in the table below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with `SQL Server 2008` reports, you can right-click on the horizontal axis and select Horizontal Axis properties. Refer screenshot #**1**. On the `Horizontal Axis Properties`, click on Labels section and select `Hide first and last labels along the axis`. Refer screenshot #**2**.

Screenshot #**3** shows sample report output **before** applying the change. Screenshot #**4** shows sample report output **after** applying the change.

Screenshots were taken using `SSRS 2008 R2`.

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

Comment: perfect.  In 2010 ReportViewer Chart control it is called Axis Properties rather than Horizontal Axis. many thanks!